# Spring Batch reading from Oracle View

Tags: spring-batch

I have an external Oracle Database for which I have access only to one view.
It will take more than 40 minutes for the view to provide results for which there are around 50,000 records in resultset.

We do not have control on optimizing the oracle view.

I have to process the resultset and persist to a table in another postgres database

Is using Spring Batch recommended for my requirement?

Comment: No need to duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222840/calling-oracle-view-in-spring-batch

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Batch will work fine for this